# Combining a Future with and_then throws compilation error in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to be comfortable with the idioms of handing *Future* in Rust.

The idea is that there are two *async* functions: one's output is another's input.

The first function pairs a bunch of integers along with a bunch of characters.

```
async fn squeeze_in(elems: [i32;5]) -> Data1 {
    let allowed_chars = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
    let together = zip(allowed_chars,elems);
    let mut data1 = Data1::new();
    for _i in together {
        data1.append(_i.0,_i.1);
    }
    data1
}
```

The other one, takes this list of pairs and gives the the same list but the positions of the elements in a pair, *reversed* .

```
async fn blow_out(data1: &Data1) -> Data1Reversed {
     let holder: Vec<(i32,char)> = vec![];
     let reversed = data1.val1.iter()
         .fold(
             holder,
             | mut accu, next_pair |  {
                 accu.push((next_pair.1,next_pair.0));
                 accu
             }
         );

      Data1Reversed::new(reversed)
}
```

The structs `Data1` and `Data1Reversed` are defined, thus:

```
use std::iter::zip;
use futures::{StreamExt, TryFutureExt};
use futures::FutureExt;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Data1 {
    pub val1: Vec<(char,i32)>
}

impl Data1 {
    pub fn new() -> Data1 {
        Data1 { val1: vec![] }
    }

    pub fn append(&mut self, elem_char: char, elem_int: i32) {
        self.val1.push((elem_char,elem_int));
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Data1Reversed {
    pub val2: Vec<(i32,char)>
}

impl Data1Reversed {
    pub fn new(elems: Vec<(i32,char)>) -> Data1Reversed {
        Data1Reversed {
            val2: elems
        }
    }
}
```

This arrangement, where two functions are called one after the other, after `await`ing, works.

However, I want to arrange the flow in a continuation, thus:

```
let squeezed_and_blown = squeeze_in(some_num).and_then(move |data1| blow_out(&data1)) ;
```

My understanding is that, each of the functions being *async*, each produces a `future`. A flow like a `future1.and_then(future2)` should be permissible. The compiler doesn't think so, though:

```
error[E0599]: the method `and_then` exists for opaque type `impl futures::Future<Output = Data1>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:38:51
   |
38 |     let squeezed_and_blown = squeeze_in(some_num).and_then(|data1| blow_out(&data1) ) ;
   |                                                   ^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `impl futures::Future<Output = Data1>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `impl futures::Future<Output = Data1>: TryFuture`
           which is required by `impl futures::Future<Output = Data1>: TryFutureExt`
           `&impl futures::Future<Output = Data1>: TryFuture`
           which is required by `&impl futures::Future<Output = Data1>: TryFutureExt`
           `&mut impl futures::Future<Output = Data1>: TryFuture`
           which is required by `&mut impl futures::Future<Output = Data1>: TryFutureExt`
```

I have visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168863/take-ownership-of-closure-argument-for-rust-future-in-and-then) conversation, if I get an hint of where I am going wrong, but that is not the case. The problem in my case, is with the first future and **not** what is provided to `and_then`.

What is confusing me is this message from the compiler:

```
error[E0599]: the method `and_then` exists for opaque type `impl futures::Future<Output = Data1>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
```

What is it unhappy about?

In response to @Jmb's comment below, here is how I want to use the functions:

```
// Here, a single future is used. However, the actual functionality requires a set of
    // futures to be launched.
    let maybe_reveresed = 
        tokio::spawn({
            squeeze_in(some_num)
            .and_then(|data1| { blow_out(&data1) })
            // and, I can add many such operations, serially here.
        }
    );
    
    // Here again, the actual functionality requires us to join a number of futures obtained earlier.
    let have_we_got_it_reversed = maybe_reveresed.await;
    
    // .. rest of implementation.
```

Comment: Do the functions really need to be async? In your examples, since they don't `await` anything you could just replace them with regular functions…

Comment: @Jmb Good point. Actually, this is a example snippet of a larger application (the structs and their impls shown here are simplified because the data doesn't matter for the question's context). Still, to give a better context, I will expand the question's code itself. Thanks.